# Get to length of children elements for an element by tag name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js

I am trying to get length of li in my code which is a list under list.

```js
$(`ul.topnav > li`).each(function() {
  console.log($(this).children("ul li").length);
});
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<ul class="topnav">
  <li>Item 1
    <ul>
      <li class="topnav1">Nested item 1</li>
      <li class="topnav1">Nested item 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Item 2
    <ul>
      <li class="topnav1">Nested item 1</li>
      <li class="topnav1">Nested item 2</li>
      <li class="topnav1">Nested item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Item 3
    <ul>
      <li class="topnav1">Nested item 1</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

But the length seems to print 0 for every element.
However if I do this:

```
$(`ul.topnav > li`).each(function() {
  console.log($(this).children().children().length);
});
```

then it is printing correct i.e. 2,3,1.

But Can I get to nth children by tag name. What I am missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is because `children()` is looking for child elements that match the `ul li` selector. This is not possible, as they can only be `ul` elements.

To fix this I'd suggest you use `find()` instead. If you specifically only want the first level of `li` elements you can use `> ul > li` as the selector.

```js
$(`ul.topnav > li`).each(function() {
  console.log($(this).find("ul li").length);
});
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<ul class="topnav">
  <li>Item 1
    <ul>
      <li class="topnav1">Nested item 1</li>
      <li class="topnav1">Nested item 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Item 2
    <ul>
      <li class="topnav1">Nested item 1</li>
      <li class="topnav1">Nested item 2</li>
      <li class="topnav1">Nested item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Item 3
    <ul>
      <li class="topnav1">Nested item 1</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```